# Where should I put a question about servers in a home environment?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

Where should I put a question about servers in a home environment? The Server Fault FAQ says, "...related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity," and "and it is not about anything in a home setting." I have a website running from my computer at home and was wondering where I should put questions pertaining to it.

Comment: What kind of a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) could be the site where to ask such questions, as the accepted questions are about:

- Computer hardware
- Computer software
- Personal and home computer networking

Questions about the following topics are off-topic:

- Videogames or consoles
- Websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
- Electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
- Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks
- A shopping or buying recommendation

Alternatively, if the question is about Apple computers, you can ask the question on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

> but the second one was about how to set up a Telnet server.

If it's a question that would be **a totally good fit on Server Fault** except for the fact that it's for a *home* environment instead of a professional one, I would fire away on SF and pretend I'm doing this in a professional capacity. That Telnet question you mention may fit well in that category.

[On the Internet, no one knows.....](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog)

Comment: Okay, two things. The two questions I asked there really didn't belong on Server Fault. For the telnet one, I made it obvious that I was in a home environment, and for the first one, it was a programming question. But now, because of those two questions, I'm banned from posting on Server Fault.

Comment: @boj what, because of *two questions?* Wow, that stinks. That said though, looking at the questions, both of them aren't good fits for *any* SE site in their current form really - they are extremely basic, and lack detail. I think that's the main reason why they got treated badly. Always make sure you Google first and get the  basics in order (like `Windows telnet server`). Then ask when/if you run into problems, add what you've done so far and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the question I'd go with either:

- [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/):

  > Pro Webmasters - Stack Exchange is for professional and enthusiast webmasters. If your question generally covers the operation of websites which you control, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

or

- [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) for more specific questions about site performance, etc.